# DynamoDB is saving the json object with wrong key and value positions on Javascript SDK

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-js

the key and value positions are saving with wrong order in dynamoDB

for example..

if i send a put command with

{
"name 1" : "value 1",
"name 2" : "value 2",
"name 3" : "value 3",
}

it saves:

{
"name 2" : "value 2",
"name 1" : "value 1",
"name 3" : "value 3",
}

how to avoid this ?

Comment: The property order does not make sense in a json object.

Comment: so dynamo really mixes the property order after saving and there is nothing to do about it ? it affect a visual query after... and when you load the json to a web form directly. any ideas how to overcome this via JS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is this npm package !

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-order?activeTab=readme